# CSS: Set width of an element to (width calculated by browser) + (20px)

Tags: css, browser, width

I am trying to set the width of an element using CSS.

I need to set the width of the element to the width calculated by the browser + 20px.

I need to do something like this: `width: auto + 20px;`

Any ideas on how to write this correctly? Thanks!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3YCnW/

Comment: Couldn't you just add 20px of padding?

Comment: Can't use padding for this scenario. I am adding this additional 20px because more text is going to be added to the element later using JS. The 20px is to accommodate this text. if I use padding, it doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: calculated ?? you mean the browser's width?

Comment: @Danko: I am referring to the width of the element that would be calculated by the browser if the CSS was set `width:auto;`

Comment: ok you need Jquery or pure javascript

Comment: width: calc(100% - 1em); is still buggy in webkit, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc the alternative is using jquery to grap the width of the auto width element in pixel values and then add 20 pixels to it.

Comment: @Wayne & Danko : Would you be able to provide any pointers to how it could be achieved in javascript if possible? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jquery you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var w = $('div').width()+20+'px';
  $('div').css('width',w);
})
```

The Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/H2enB/**

And with pure Javascript

```
var w = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetWidth + 20 +"px";
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width = w;
```

The Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/E9x95/5/**

Comment: need to do this for all the `td` elements on the page. how can this been done in pure JS. thanks

Comment: i have added this code. i believe someone has to peer review it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: block;` and `width: calc( 100% + 20px );`... no JS required

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/muFH3/

Comment: works like a charm! this is what i was looking for. didn't realize that specifying `100%` here is similar to `auto`

Comment: i take that back... setting `display: block` causes undesired results that I didn't realize earlier. see: [JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muFH3/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/muFH3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

`var element = document.getElementById('my_element_id');`

`element.style.width = (parseInt(element.offsetWidth) + 20)+"px";`